# Why can't I have a direct INSERT statement within my SQL Scripting stored procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My stored procedure works fine if I use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT...'; inside the stored procedure.

But it seem over complicated to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE as it looks like we can just write INSERT...

So this extract of my stored procedure works

```
IF ( :DB_NAME IS NOT NULL ) THEN

    DEST_DB_NAME := REGEXP_REPLACE(:DB_NAME, '^' || :ENV_SOURCE, :ENV_DEST);

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO CENTRAL.AUDIT.CLONING_HISTORY(SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT, SOURCE_DATABASE, DEST_ENVIRONMENT, DEST_DATABASE, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, OPERATION)
            VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ''CLONE'')'
            USING (ENV_SOURCE, DB_NAME, ENV_DEST, DEST_DB_NAME, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP);

    SQL := 'CREATE DATABASE ' || :DEST_DB_NAME ||' CLONE ' || :DB_NAME || ' AT(TIMESTAMP => \'' || AS_OF_TIMESTAMP::STRING || '\'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL;
```

But if I try to replace the first EXECUTE IMMEDIATE by a direct insert, I get a weird error message when trying to create the procedure

```
IF ( :DB_NAME IS NOT NULL ) THEN

    DEST_DB_NAME := REGEXP_REPLACE(:DB_NAME, '^' || :ENV_SOURCE, :ENV_DEST);

    INSERT INTO AUDIT.CLONING_HISTORY(SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT, SOURCE_DATABASE, DEST_ENVIRONMENT, DEST_DATABASE, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, OPERATION)
        VALUES(ENV_SOURCE, DB_NAME, ENV_DEST, DEST_DB_NAME, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, 'CLONE')';

    SQL := 'CREATE DATABASE ' || :DEST_DB_NAME ||' CLONE ' || :DB_NAME || ' AT(TIMESTAMP => \'' || AS_OF_TIMESTAMP::STRING || '\'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL;
```

I do not understand the error msg either

> SQL compilation error:
> syntax error line 48 at position 8 unexpected 'DB_NAME'.
> syntax error line 48 at position 16 unexpected ':='.

I tried replacing my somewhat complex insert statement by a much simpler and I get the same error

```
INSERT INTO Whatever.SomeColumn(33);
```

PS: I would like to attach the entire procedure script but can't see how to do this!

It is just looping through some databases to clone them under a different name, and log this action in a table within the current database

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use variables with static `INSERT` inside Snowflake Scripting block:

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT.CLONING_HISTORY(SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT, SOURCE_DATABASE,
                                  DEST_ENVIRONMENT, DEST_DATABASE,
                                  AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, OPERATION)
VALUES(ENV_SOURCE, DB_NAME, ENV_DEST, DEST_DB_NAME, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, 'CLONE');
```

should be (`var` => `:var`):

```
INSERT INTO AUDIT.CLONING_HISTORY(SOURCE_ENVIRONMENT, SOURCE_DATABASE,
                                  DEST_ENVIRONMENT, DEST_DATABASE,
                                  AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, OPERATION)
SELECT :ENV_SOURCE, :DB_NAME, :ENV_DEST, :DEST_DB_NAME, :AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, 'CLONE';
```

More at: [Using a Variable in a SQL Statement (Binding)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding)

Comment: Thanks for the link but apparently the : is not always required (although I am  not entirely clear when it is and when it is not)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually embarrassing but it was a personal Boo Boo...

I had left a trailing single quote in my INSERT statement...

```
, AS_OF_TIMESTAMP, 'CLONE')';
```

There should not have been a ' before the ; !!!